# InvalidCastException when adding new item to table

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I am trying to add a new item to a table however the below code is throwing an InvalidCastException.

This is from the add item page to add a new item into my table.
The WineDate is coming from a DatePicker, WineStars from a ListPicker, and Category is coming from a listpicker linked to a table

```
WineItem newWineItem = new WineItem
            {
                WineDate = wineDatepurchasedTextbox.Value.Value.Date,
                WineComments = wineCommentsTextBox.Text,
                WineStars = (string)StarList.SelectedItem,
                WineType = wineTypeTextbox.Text,
                WineVinyard = wineVineyardTextbox.Text,
                WineYear = wineYearTextbox.Text,
                Category = (WineCategory)winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem

            };
```

please let me know if you need any further information to help me.

Comment: Probably the line where the exception is thrown will help a lot.

Comment: Post your table definition and the stack trace with detailed exception description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only performing two casts: You're casting `StarList.SelectedItem` to a `string` and you're casting `winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem` to a `WineCategory`. You should attach the debugger and view what these values *actually* are to determine what you're doing wrong.

(This assumes that none of the property setters in `WineItem` perform casting, but I'm going for the obvious solution first.)

Comment: +1 Nice catch - it's a near certainty that it's the cast to `WineCategory` that's broken.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although not what was actually wrong with my code while checking this I resolved it. 
The error was actually in my XMAL

Answer (score 0):

```
Category = (WineCategory)winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem
```

If `winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem` is a class that inherits WineCategory, you can do this, otherwise you have to declare such a class or create a constructor that accept the type of `winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem`:

```
Category = new WineCategory(winecategoriesListPicker.SelectedItem);
```